# Insert to CLOB through ODP.NET

Tags: database, oracle, odp.net, clob

I am using ODP.NET and Oracle database. I have to save to CLOB field data more than 4000 length. When I am doing this through simple SQL statement and ExecuteNonQuery exception occurs - PLS-00172: string literal too long.
The question is how to save this lond data?
I cannot use/create procedures - no way to get permission. I can only use ODP.NET.

Comment: In this case ask your DBA for a solution if he does not allow you to create a function.

Comment: Please show us your code.